# given a list of strings in python

Tags: python, list

I have the following code in python:

```
class CreateMap:
   def changeme(listOne, lisrTwo, listThree, listFour, listfive):

if __name__ == "__main__":
        createMap = CreateMap()
        createMap.changeme(["oneItem", "secondItem"],[],[],[],[])
```

It gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: changeme() takes exactly 5 arguments (6 given)
```

As I understand, it recognize the first list as two list. How can I avoid it?

Comment: You would receive the exact same error if your first argument were null. The problem is that you're trying to call a static function as if it were a method (which passes the instance, createMap, as the first argument).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your function as

```
def changeme(self,listOne, lisrTwo, listThree, listFour, listfive):
```

This will make the function accessible to instance variables outside the class

Answer (score 0):

It's not recognizing the first list as two lists. You must use `self` as the first argument in your function, because **explicit is better than implicit**. The reasoning has been given [here](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-must-self-be-used-explicitly-in-method-definitions-and-calls) in detail. I'll quote some here.

> First, it’s more obvious that you are using a method or instance attribute instead of a local variable. Reading self.x or self.meth() makes it absolutely clear that an instance variable or method is used even if you don’t know the class definition by heart.